# Потоки, количество и правильный их расчет в работе

Tags: c#, многопоточность, потоки-данных

вопрос по поводу потоков, работаю с Post запросами (туда-обратно с параметрами) на внешний ресурс, потоки запускаю вот так:
*Опыта 1 день в данной теме, не судите строго если что не так.

```
Threads = new Thread[100];
for (int i = 0; i < CountThreads; i++) {
                Threads[i] = new Thread(Program.Checking);
                Threads[i].IsBackground = true;
                Threads[i].Start();
            }
```

Для примера я выполняю 400 запросов, с определенным значением CountThreads (1,6,300) вот временные характеристики скорости работы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сервер же намертво отключается при более 100 потоков (Обрабатывает только мои запросы из вне), вот и сам вопрос, я правильно понимаю что причина отсутствия увеличения скорости при увеличении количества потоков -  то что сервер не успевает обрабатывать запросы или все-таки вероятнее код не оптимален? Порадует любая инфа.

Добавлю, при выполнении идентичного php скрипта с одного сервера Post запросом на другой сервер:
Время выполнения скрипта: 53.8089 сек.  (400 выполнений)
При выполнении кода просто циклом в static void Main скорость примерно как при 6'ти потоках.

*Прикрепляю

```
public static void CreateThreads()
        {
            IsWork = true;
            Threads = new Thread[500];

            for (int i = 0; i < CountThreads; i++)
            {
                if (i > CountThreads)
                {
                    break;
                }

                Threads[i] = new Thread(Program.Checking);
                Threads[i].IsBackground = true;
                Threads[i].Start();
            }
        }

static private void Checking()
        {
            while (IsWork)
            {
                string response = "";
                try
                {
                    ird++;
                    response = UseGo(ird);
                }
                catch { }
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }


static string UseGo(int irt)
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = " [ Данные JSON ] ";
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine("[Process Thread] Complite: " + irt);
                return result;
            }
        }
```

И вызываю в Main вот так:

```
      CreateThreads();
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109601/discussion-on-question-by-alex-solomon------).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Вы используете `HttpWebRequest`, который устарел, и для .NET Core совершенно нет причин его использовать, вместо него есть `HttpClient`. К тому же он умеет переиспользовать открытые TCP соединения, что ускоряет время "запрос-ответ" для последующих запросов на один и тот же сервер.
2. Создание нового потока `Thread` - тоже очень дорогая штука, но есть очень удобный класс `Task`, который умеет переиспользовать потоки из пула потоков, и к тому же позволяет писать асинхронный код с помощью `async/await`.
3. Для преобразования Json в объекты и наоборот, в .NET Core существует отличный парсер `System.Text.Json`, кстати сравнительно молодой, но весьма шустрый.

Почитайте про все про это, а я просто покажу вам пример реализации того, что вы делаете с помощью всего вышеперечисленного.

Классы для запроса и ответа, наполните их необходимыми свойствами. Запрос будет читаться из класса-источника, ответ соответсвенно будет заноситься в экземпляр класс-приемника путем Json сереиализации и десереализации.

```csharp
public class JsonRequestData
{
    [JsonPropertyName("param1")]
    public string Param1 { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("param2")]
    public string Param2 { get; set; }
}

public class JsonResponseData
{
    [JsonPropertyName("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Я создал вот такой простой класс, ну чтобы не париться со статическими полями и методами в классе `Program`.

В методе `SendHttpPost` я собрал всю сетевую работу и преобразования. Наверняка есть способы проще и понятнее, комментаторы меня поправят, но писал на коленке и не тестировал, так как не имею сейчас подходящего сервера, принимающего POST запросы.

В методе `Run` реализовал алгоритм по запуску общего количества запросов с ограничением на количество одновременно выполняющихся.

```csharp
public class MyHttpManager
{
    private readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    private readonly JsonSerializerOptions serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true, Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping };
    private readonly JsonSerializerOptions deserializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions { ReadCommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip };

    public async Task Run()
    {
        JsonRequestData jsonRequestData = new JsonRequestData();
        jsonRequestData.Param1 = "val1";
        jsonRequestData.Param2 = "val2";

        int numRequests = 400; // сколько запросов отправить
        int maxConcurrentTasks = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2; // сколько одновременно работающих задач
        SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrentTasks);
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numRequests; i++)
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync(); // ждать, если активно максимальное число задач, пока место не освободится
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                JsonResponseData jsonResponseData = await SendHttpPost<JsonResponseData>("https://example.org/api/method", jsonRequestData);
                Console.WriteLine(jsonResponseData?.Status ?? "[Task] Null response");
                semaphore.Release();
            }));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // ждать завершения всех задач            
    }

    private async Task<T> SendHttpPost<T>(string url, object data) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            string text = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, serializeOptions);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
            using HttpContent content = new StringContent(text, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            using Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            T result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(responseStream, deserializeOptions);

            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("[Task] Complete: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

И вот так это все стартует, обратите внимание на асинхронный `Main`

```csharp
public class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        MyHttpManager manager = new MyHttpManager();
        await manager.Run();

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("[Main] All complete: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Разберите пример, попробуйте его заставить работать в ваших условиях.

Кстати, вот результат сериализации экземпляра класса `JsonRequestData`, использованного в коде выше.

```
{
  "param1": "val1",
  "param2": "val2"
}
```

---

Как достать `string` из ответа. Для этого надо его прочитать полностью, а я передаю сразу поток получения в десереализацию.

Можно вот этот фрагмент

```csharp
using Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
T result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(responseStream, deserializeOptions);
```

Заменить вот на этот, это правда будет кушать немного больше памяти, так как получаемый ответ будет читаться в память полностью.

```csharp
string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
// responseText здесь - то что вам нужно.
T result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(responseText, deserializeOptions);
```

Comment: спасибо большое, проверил работоспособность вашего кода, так же сравнил с другими моими вариациями:

[Ваш Async] 400 запросов - 37 секунд, 10.000 запросов - 16 минут. 33мб память процессора. ЦП 6-7% [Web сервер работает стабильно]

[Мой из вопроса] 400 запросов - 40 секунд, 10.000 запросов - 16 минут. 137мб память процессора. ЦП 7-10%  [Web сервер ложиться почти намертво, или получает ответ в течении 1-2 минут]

[Мой Async] 400 запросов - 60 секунд, 10.000 запросов - 24 минуты 23 секунд. 30мб память процессора. ЦП 7-9% [Web сервер работает стабильно]

Comment: Получается ваш способ менее затратный по ресурсам)) Вопрос кстати по async, как можно получить result типа такого? var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
А то в async имею только response где headers а сам ответ сервера не могу достать....  т.e. content в обоих случаях async пишет null. А по факту примерно такой:
{
    "d": {
        "Result": 0,
        "Success": true,
        "Warning": null,
    }
}

Comment: @AlexSolomon дополнил ответ.

Comment: @AlexSolomon вы еще в моем примере можете вручную подрегулировать количство одновременно работающих запросов. Это может как ускорить, так и земедлить процесс, в зависимости от значения. Кстати, мой пример один из самых простых с использованием cовременных .NET API, но я уверен, есть еще места, где что-то можно оптимизировать.

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение и информативность, было очень интересно)) Кстати, вообще по сути безопасности я правильно понимаю что на Web сервере нужно настроить блокирование такого количества запросов с одного ip, как понимаю иначе открывает возможность брутфорса запросов и Dos атаку (web ложится)

Comment: @AlexSolomon конечно можно, только не забывайте про повсеместно используемый провайдерами NAT, но это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: Начал про NAT читать, уже интересно)

Comment: @AlexSolomon ваша главная проблема сейчас - сервер, который очень медленно отвечает. 400 запросов за 37 секунд - это ~10 запросов в секунду. А люди на обычном железе до 100 000 запросов в секунду делают, и это далеко не потолок. Сервер должен выдерживать как минимум 100 таких одновременно тестирующих клиентов как ваше приложение без просадки по производительности, а при вашей нагрузке время ответа должно быть примерно как ping до сервера. Реальная цифра, на которую советую ориентироваться - 100 запросов в секунду на одного клиента. Тогда я не смогу положить ваш сервер со своего мобильника.

Comment: да, спасибо за пометку, я понимаю это, но сервер партнеров, я и так собирался им разъяснить всю это ситуацию, так как мне нужна стабильная работоспособность с их стороны