# Потоки и задержка их выполнения c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, многопоточность, task

У меня есть код, который обрабатывает некие данные. Распишу чуть ниже.
Я создаю потоки таким кодом

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.thread; i++)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(Checker)
        {
            Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest
        };
        th.Start();
    }
```

В каждом потоке запускается `Parallel.For`. Обработка заключается в том, что есть некий `List<string>` с аккаунтами (log:pass), каждый цикл вытягивается аккаунт и через api делаются запросы к серверу и идет обработка полученного запроса (в основном получаю картинку - работаю/сохраняю ее)
Вот код который отвечает за запись/выдачу аккаунта

```
private List<string> account = new List<string>();
public string Account
    {
        get
        {
            lock (account)
            {
                if (account.Count != 0)
                {
                    string _account = account[0];
                    account.Remove(_account);

                    return _account;
                }
                return "Account 0";
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (account)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                {
                    account.Add(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

И стоит такая задача, есть сторонняя программа которая подхватывает картинки из моей и тоже их обрабатывает и шлет ответ в мою, ну и дальше по сценарию. Программа которая подхватывает слишком сильно грузит процессор, не всегда, но бывает. Хотелось бы сделать ползунок на подобии "таймаут между действиями" в миллисекундах чтобы разгрузить проц.
Задача странная как и весь код. Помогите исправить недостатки кода и как можно сделать таймаут? уф

Comment: Таймаут где? Вы же не показали ни `Parallel.For`, ни что вашм потоки делаеют, ни зачем вам тут вообще многопоточность (а не асинхронность).

Comment: @tym32167 Таймаут между циклами. Хорошо, попробую узнать про асинхронность. Спасибо

Comment: Суть в том, что вот вы, например, создвли 10 потоков. В каждом из них запустили по `Parallel.For`, который создаст ещё потоков. И вся эта братия потоков будет ждать, когда ответит веб запрос? Для операций с сетью как раз можно использовать асинхронность. Или хотя бы, как минимум, вы можете подумать об уменьшении количества потоков вместо добавления ожиления.

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1143379/373567

Comment: @aepot спасибо, то что надо